Wordpress Contact Form 7 two loading bar Problem
When I set up the Contact Form 7 with this code. I fill the form and press the submit button, it show two loading bar. How can I fix it? ↓

[text* text-44]
[tel* your-phone minlength:8 maxlength:8]
[email* email-567]
[select* menu-704 "— 請選取分店 —""銅鑼灣(港鐵站)""觀塘(港鐵站)""尖沙咀(港鐵站)"]
[date* date-start min:today+1days step:1 class:required]
[select* menu-964 "— 請選取選項 —" "10AM – 11AM *只適用於星期六及公眾假期" "11AM – 12PM *只適用於星期六及公眾假期" "1PM – 2PM" "2PM – 3PM" "3PM – 4PM" "4PM – 5PM" "5PM – 6PM" "6PM – 7PM *只適用於星期一至五" "7PM – 8PM *只適用於星期一至五"]


ㅤ請選擇付款方法:
[radio radio-343 use_label_element default:1"1"]
[radio radio-343 use_label_element default:2"2"]

我已閱讀並同意有關


            
============
I try to build a form

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
